# restrict django choice field on django admin per user

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have an exam like this:

```
class Exam(BaseModel):
    ...
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        (PASS, PASS),
        (FAILED, FAILED),
        (GREAT, GREAT),
    state = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATE_CHOICES, default=PASS)
    ...
```

Inside Django admin, I want the user with group X to be able to only change the state only from FAILED to PASS.
and users with group Y be able to change the state from FAILED to PASS and PASS to GREAT.
here is my admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Exam)
class ExamAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('state',)
```

Does anyone know a solution for it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564705/how-to-limit-the-number-of-choices-in-django-admin Have a look at this. The example here works with querysets, but you can replace the queryset with a plain old list like above.

Comment: Checking this topic for hours and still cannot understand the solution to my problem.
@nigel239

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work;

```
class AdminExamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    options
    ...

class ExamForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        (PASS, PASS),
        (FAILED, FAILED),
        (GREAT, GREAT),
    state = forms.CharField(choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = Exam
        fields = ('state',)
    ...

@admin.register(Exam)
class ExamModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    fields = ('state',)
    list_display = ('state',)
    form = ExamForm
    ...

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_admin or request.user.is_superuser:
            return AdminExamForm
        else:
            return ExamForm
```

###### Sorry for giving you a bad example before, didn't have too much time.

### This is how you could access the user, *if* your exam model has one.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Exam(BaseModel):
    ...
    STATE_CHOICES = (
        (PASS, PASS),
        (FAILED, FAILED),
        (GREAT, GREAT),
    state = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATE_CHOICES, default=PASS)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user.is_admin or self.user.is_superuser:
            ... your logic here
        super(Exam,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

### To access the request in the create/save method:

- Pass it into the kwargs of the create/save method, of the form you want.
- Then get the request in the create/save method, and do your logic

```
request = kwargs.get('request',None)
```

#### Edit, to get the request into the model's `.save()`

Django admin's save model function literally just calls `obj.save()`
So if you pass `request=request` into save like so:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    """
    Given a model instance save it to the database.
    """
    obj.save(request=request)
```

it should work.

#### Override Admin save:

[Override save method of Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36443245/override-save-method-of-django-admin/36443466#36443466)

Comment: Thanks but how can you get user from and show restrict the choices or this model for group of users?

Comment: @MehdiAria Edited my answer, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Is this possible to make this restriction through models instead of ModelAdmin?

Comment: Ehhm, yes! That is possible. You would need to override the save method -> override save method -> check if the instance's user is a superuser -> if the user is not a superuser, simply don't save the object (don't call `super().save()`). or alternatively use model object permissions. But, you would also have to implement these checks anywhere else, would be weird if a user saw a create page, that they couldn't create anything on. @MehdiAria

Comment: But how can I access to request and user inside that method? can you replace the answer with that one, please? @nigel239

Comment: @MehdiAria You don't nescessarily need the request. If the Exam model has a `user` field, you can use this to check.

Comment: It doesn't have the user field @nigel239

Comment: Can you find a way to override the create method of the admin form? You can then pass the request object into the kwargs of `.create(request=request)`, and then in the `.create` method you add: `request = kwargs.get('request',None)`

Comment: I prefer to don't use the admin forms for that

Comment: @MehdiAria it doesn't matter which form, but this should work for both.

Comment: Dude this save self doesn't have any user

Comment: You don't need a user. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs You could also do this with `mymodel.save(request=request)` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73408390/django-custom-model-save-method-for-a-non-persisted-attribute/73408412#73408412

Comment: Thanks so much, @nigel239 but I want to do the job without using forms. I want to access the user in the same method of my model.

Comment: It's literally what I have been telling you @MehdiAria, you can also override the save method, and do the exact same. Just pass `request=request` into the save method, and then inside of `save()` do `request = kwargs.get('request',None)`

Comment: From where I should pass the request? @nigel239 Should I override another method for that inside the model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247479/discussion-between-mehdi-aria-and-nigel239).